# How does/should the communication happen between Service Provider and Actual application in SAML?

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml, shibboleth

I understand that the communication between IDP and SP is well defined in standard. I'm wondering what are the ways to make the custom communication happen between standalone SP and the actual application.

I assume the standard ways exists, without reinventing the wheel my self. But even `spring-saml security` only talks about "custom mechanism" doesn't say what it is.

Can someone point to me the right direction? I've searched but I'm surprised that it's not written anywhere blogs, tutorials etc. Not even in Shibboleth/Gluu documentation, that part is somehow left alone.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From pure SAML point of view the 'actual application' has to implement a SAML service provider, e.g. like the Spring SAML sample application does.

If the 'actual application' is not able to do this , e.g. because it's a some product without extension points you need to check the capabilities of the application with regards to SSO.
E.g. some apps allow to use a custom HTTP request header to provide SSO. Then you could use an HTTP reverse-proxy which injects that header based on a SAML assertion, e.g. Apache http server with mod_auth_mellon.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr I woudln't have had to worry about this if I had found a solution for IdpProxy scenario. Even shibboleth has no way to do that. Do you know about IdpProxy?

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr is openam free?

Comment: If you build it from source it's free of charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem essentially boils down to *"how can two applications deployed in a trusted network securely communicate with each other in order to exchange security information about a user"*. It's the same problem SAML solves for applications communicating over untrusted network and it's made easier by the fact that both the authentication point (SP) and the application are under control of the same entity = it's e.g. easier to use symetric cryptography. The SP can in principle communicate with the app using either front-end channel (= through web browser), or back-end channel (= directly between each other over network).

There are different ways to perform the communication (using one, the other, or both channels), most can be implemented using some of the available security products. Here are some ideas:

**Both SP and application are sharing the same domain (= user's web browser accesses them on a URL which shares cookies)**

- you can configure your SP to store a cookie - a piece of information including e.g. UID and expiration of the authenticated user, the cookie can be encrypted using a shared secret known to both SP and the application. This is approach used e.g. by OpenAM, or Wildfly with shared domain encrypted cookie.
- an alternative of this approach is to send the information about the authenticated user from SP to the application e.g. as an encrypted HTTP POST parameter - similar approach which SAML does, just much more basic.
- same approach could be enhanced by using another secure shared storage - e.g. a database and sending just a reference to a record (e.g. a unique secret session ID)

**SP can be used as HTTP proxy for the application**

- in this case you can pass the authentication information as an HTTP header to the application, you must ensure that going through SP is the only way the application can be accessed. This is only practical when the SP is part of e.g. a load balancer (e.g. Apache / Nginx plugin).

**SP and application could use a standard authentication mechanism to communicate the authentication data**

- you could use e.g. Kerberos (which is anyway based on shared-secret encryption) or OAuth

Each of the option might have different attack vectors and possible vulnerabilities.

My opinion is that adding SAML functionality directly into the application, using the HTTP proxy with SAML support, or a standard product which handles the last mile authentication between SP and the application (e.g. OpenAM) is the best way to go. Implementing custom security mechanism might seem easy, but there's a lot of room for making a mistake which leaves the whole solution vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought along the same lines of Front Channel idea but as you said it's like the same problem solved by SAML. Do you know if OpenAM supports complex IDP proxy use cases? like user/email suffix based IDP selection? I actually wanted something like this implement SAML v2 IDP proxy, as there is no open source solution for that, I wanted to make SP communicate multiple IDPs while also providing the SSO, if I have SP with each application, then single sign on won't happen as they might have authenticated using different IDPs, so I wanted some proxy IDP in betweeen.

Comment: Let me explain the use case: Multiple users belonging to external organizations, multiple IDPs. But SPs are part of one organization(kind of SaaS), whenever one SP contacts IDP it should be able to authenticate if the user browser already authenticated throught that intermediate IDP. I think this link will describe more clearly: https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/GS/SAMLIdPProxy

Comment: OpenAM can act as an IDP proxy, and yes it has possibilities to define which IDP to connect to based on a range of criteria - but enabling those use-cases with OpenAM product is hard. It's a very complex (and old) product, you might need specialized consulting. The need you have is closer to enterprise single sign-on - from open-source Gluu might be able to cover this (https://www.gluu.org/), and CAS (https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas) might be even better.

Comment: Even Gluu has only SP based IDP selection where as I need user based. Gluu recommends against CAS(https://www.gluu.org/blog/to-cas-or-not-to-cas/). Thanks for your help. It helped.

Comment: From commercial things I know that IDM from www.efecte.com can do this very nicely - well, I implemented it :) But the easiest way to go - if none of the product does exactly what you need, or if there's no budget - is most likely to customize the Spring SAML.